# How to pass the id of a specific row in a table to a function in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have got the values of the database through axios and displayed them in a table. So the database contains questions and answers. When clicking on 'Show Answer', I need to display the answer of that particular question and change the text of the button to 'Hide Answer.

I have tried using this.state and this.setState to change the values. But it changes for every row in the table. But I need to change only for the particular row which has been clicked.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    questions: [],
    displayAnswer: false
    };
}
 componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/question/')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ questions: response.data })
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
 }
toggleAnswer(ques_id) {
//how do i change here for a particular row and not for the whole table
}

 render() {
return (
    <div>
        <h1>Questions</h1>
       <table>
            {
                 this.state.questions.map((questions) => (
                 <tr key={questions.id}>
                     <td>{questions.question}
                    //the question.answer goes here
                    </td>
                     <td> 
                 <button onClick={() => this.toggleAnswer(questions.id)}>{this.state.displayAnswer ? 'Hide Answer' : 'Show Answer'}</button></td>
                 </tr>
                 ))
            }
        </table>
    </div>
);
}
 }
 export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to maintain `displayAnswer` property for each question. I would suggest something like this,

```
  toggleAnswer(questionId) {
      const questions = this.state.questions.map(value=> value.id === questionId ? 
           {...value, displayAnswer : value.displayAnswer !== undefined ? !value.displayAnswer : true } : value);
      this.setState({questions})
}
```

then use `questions.displayAnswer` in `this.state.displayAnswer ? 'Hide Answer' : 'Show Answer'` here instead of `this.state.displayAnswer`